# PhpStorm debug session freezes when requesting another local PHP application

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, breakpoints

I'm developing a kinda export from one app to another.

PhpStorm PHP debug tool works perfect but I faced an issue: 
When my debugged Laravel instance sends request to the next application on my local Apache box session freezes because no answer is coming back from the second app.

When I turn off debugging it unfreezes, but run without stopping breakpoints any more and I can`t stop after response arrived any more.

I've tried to turn off all the BPs but that not helped.
I am able to debug both apps separately though.

Comment: Most likely your 2nd app also gets debugged .. but because you are already in a debug session .. it cannot do that and is waiting until firs one is over (in other words -- limited debug slots). You may increase the max number of simultaneous debug connections in PhpStorm settings. By default it's just `1`. make it `3` or so (no need to go into extreme, especially if it does not bring any benefits).

Comment: goto Preferences->language/frameworks->PHP->Debug and increase the number of simultaneous connections

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, that was it.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Thank you! Quite forgotten that I reduced when faced xdebug related performance issue.

Comment: @SergeyCherednichenko that is never going away ... there is a perf price to pay whenever the xdebug extension is enabled in your php configs. Whether you have a listening client (phpStorm) or not , xdebug will always try to establish a connexion to the configured listening port.  Make certain you nuke the extension in your production configs.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely that your 2nd app also sees "debug me" flag and Xdebug tries to debug it (depends on your Xdebug config; most likely you have `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`). But because you are already in a debug session it cannot do that and is waiting until first debug session is over (in other words -- limited debug slots).

This is typical situation: debugging website that makes API calls to another/same domain on the same server.

In such situation you should increase the max number of simultaneous debug connections in PhpStorm settings (`Settings/Prefeences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug | Max. simultaneous connections`). By default it's just `1`, make it `2` or `3` (no need to go into extreme and putting large number -- you are unlikely to see more than 2 debug sessions at once).

This way you can debug 2 requests separately (if all setup correctly) .. or 2nd one will run with no breakpoints triggered.