# How do I debug the code runned by systemd service using breakpoints?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm and my application uses a few asynchronous processes that I would like to debug.

Everything is setup to debug the rest of the application using xdebug but I haven't yet found a way to debug the services.

Here is some pseudocode presenting the running service :

```
while (true){
  message = getMessageIfAny();
  if (message){
    parseMessage(message);  // <- here is my (sadly ignored) breakpoint
  }
}
```

Response to comment :

For my setup, my application is deployed on a Vagrant VM. I am able to debug my main app using the debug cookie sent by my browser.
My main app sometimes adds a message to my DB and this message is recuperated by a service which then proceeds to handle it. The part I can't debug is the code ran by the service.

I didn't stop the "over http" debug session before trying to debug the service part. I will try that.

edit : increasing the number of maximum simultaneous connections doesn't seem to change anything

edit :
Well I'm almost there. Now when I start my service, the breakpoint is caught but I have the following message :

> cannot find file 'path/to/file.php' locally
>
> To fix it set server name by environment variable PHP_IDE_CONFIG and restart debug session

I already ran :

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=local_dev_VM"
```

here is what my php.ini looks like

```
[xdebug]
; Debug settings
zend_extension = xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = On                 ; Enable xdebug
xdebug.remote_autostart = On             ; Only start xdebug on demand, not on every request
xdebug.remote_host = "192.168.8.3"         ; This is unused if the next setting is 'On'
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On           ; Use a special $_SERVER['...'] variable to get the remote address
xdebug.remote_port = 9000                 ; Port on the IDE to connect back to. Usually it is 9000
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"                ; The IDE key which should match the XDEBUG_SESSION cookie value
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
```

and here is the settings/languages&frameworks/php/servers

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your setup. Right now it's not clear what exactly you have got there. 1) This code that you cannot debug -- is it main app or a service? 2) Are you trying to debug both calling app and called service at the same time? 3) What's your Xdebug settings; is it tries to debug every request or only those with "debug me" parameter/cookie? 4) Are you able to debug main app (calling app) right now?

Comment: In general: 1) when you debugging main (caller) app and making request to the service (API/service etc) .. and you wish to debug that API/service this way ... you either need to pass "debug me" flag together with the call (so Xdebug sees it) .. or configure Xdebug to attempt to debug every single request regardless of such flag (`xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`); 2) By default PhpStorm can handle 1 active debug session; to debug both calling app and called app in one go (separate sessions) you need to increase the limit from 1 to 2 or 3 -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51543178/783119

Comment: 1) You should leave some comments "I've updated my question with new info" with referring using `@username` (if there is more than 2 people participating).. otherwise user will not be notified on that unless manually comes back and checks the question for updates. You are the one who needs help/having questions .. so you really should make this part easier.

Comment: 2) So how does that service run? How do you call it -- via HTTP request from main app or what? If it's run by systemd .. so it's launched separately and PHP that runs it must be configured (executed) with parameters that allows debugging (that has to be done on start). P.S. You may also try placing `xdebug_break();` into such code -- it triggers debug session on demand. P.P.S. On Linux boxes it's rather normal to see that  PHP uses different php.ini when run under web server and in CLI... so keep this moment in mind.

Comment: @LazyOne, well I did wonder if/how you would be notified and indeed thanks for your help (and tips for stackoverflow use) ! The service is ran by systemd. I'm trying  xdebug_break.

Comment: OK .. so it's much clear for me now. You are basically having some queue processing service that is independent from main app (main app does not call it directly -- it just sends stuff into a queue). For me this means: no "debug me" flags or `remote_autostart` option can really be used here (well, you could  use `remote_autostart`.... you would get debug session at the service start .. and then you set breakpoints where needed and hit "Run" in IDE so it runs until breakpoint is hit or process exited).

Comment: `xdebug_break();` is a better option here. Just in case -- debug session (Xdebug establishes connection with IDE) can be initiated only once per run (but breakpoints can be hit multiple times). If anything -- collect xdebug log and look at what is happening there -- it will give some clues. https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: Another thing -- your service is basically "remote CLI app" in IDE eyes -- it does not get started from IDE with needed debug parameters. So you may need to have some config in place for IDE to accept such debug connection properly. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+CLI+scripts+with+PhpStorm & https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm in general.

Comment: So is it fully working for you or not? Maybe some slight misconfig/misunderstanding in `PHP | Servers` where path mappings are defined (the host). Check that. Other than that -- please post screenshots

Comment: @LazyOne I made progress and the breakpoint is now catched but it seems that there is a problem with the mapping (I edited my question with more info)

Comment: Show you mappings settings (whole screen). BTW, 1) if `xdebug.remote_connect_back = On` then value of `xdebug.remote_host` is ignored (in majority of situations). 2) `export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=localhost"` -- I would give it other `unique` name rather than `localhost` (unless it's all debugged on the same host OS).

Comment: @LazyOne I added a screenshot of the servers settings. I set the remote_connect_back to Off and rename the server (and well it doesn't catch the breakpoint anymore so I must have broken something..)

Comment: @LazyOne ok i had also changed autostart. So I am back at the situation where I catch the breakpoint but have the PHP_IDE_CONFIG error

Comment: 1) I assume that actual `local<->remote` paths mapping is correct (that the remote path is final and has no symlink anywhere in `/var/www/erms`).  2) In `PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=localhost"` string the `localhost` must be equal to `local_dev_VM` (from your last screenshot) -- as you can see they are different. That's why I suggested to have a unique name to avoid any possible confusion with such standard names.

Comment: 3) remote_connect_back & autostart -- if xdebug log shows that it connects and does it to correct IP ... then do not worry / leave as is. Feel free to revert back if it worked better for you then. 4) If it still reports "cannot match file" -- see what extra logging from IDE side may show: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs. Since I do not know your real paths/real locations ... it;s hard to suggest anything more concrete for me.

Comment: 1) the mapping is valid and with no symlink 2) I re-exported PHP_IDE_CONFIG with the new server name 3) for now it only work with remote_host set with the ip. I will leave it like this for now. 4) It still report "cannot match" so I added some line to try and learn more. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I get the notification to "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" and I think it doesn't have a lot in common with the initial problem so I will close the question. I will try again on my own and see if I need to create a new question. Have a good day :)